# React/Redux Changing background colour of button in nested array using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been scratching my head over this for ages now.

**I am trying to change the background colour of a specific button that is in a nested array.**

I have an array of names in pairs that I loop over twice using a map, once to get the pair and once again to get the value. I output and assign the values to a button for each and am displaying the pairs together (E.g. each pair is indexed 0 and 1).

When I click on the button I wish to change only the background colour of the selected button. Currently all the buttons change colour. The issue being is that the state of the buttons effects all of them when I use a boolean to define the selection.

The handler I am using to do this also adds the value of the button to an array to be passed into global state later on as well.

Any help with this would be greatly greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find a way past it. Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../App.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "../Button/Button";

class Matches extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      champ: [],
      winningPlayers: [],
      selected: false,
    };
    this.handleAddWinners = this.handleAddWinners.bind(this);
    this.handleRound = this.handleRound.bind(this);
  }

  // Adds winners to a local array which is then sent
  // to the global array using the handleNextRound action.

  handleAddWinners = (e) => {
    const winner = e.target.value;
    const { champ } = this.state;
    const { round } = this.props;

    if (round !== 3) {
      this.setState({
        selected: !false,
        winningPlayers: [...this.state.winningPlayers, winner],
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ champ: [...champ, winner] });
    }
  };

  handleRound = () => {
    const { round, handleNextRound, handleChampion } = this.props;

    round !== 3 ? handleNextRound(this.state) : handleChampion(this.state);

    this.setState({ winningPlayers: [] });
  };

  render() {
    const { pairs, round, handleClear, roundWinners, champion } = this.props;
    const { winningPlayers, selected, champ } = this.state;
    const semi = roundWinners[0];
    const final = roundWinners[1];
    const champName = champion.map((item) => item);
    const reset =
      round !== 4 ? "block__reset__tournament" : "block__reset__new-game";
    const newGame = `${round !== 4 ? "Reset" : "New Game?"}`;
    const buttonClick = `${selected ? "selected" : "block__player"}`;
   

    return (
      <>
        <div classname="container__wrapper">
          <div className="container__tournament">
            {round === 1 ? (
              <section className="block__round ">
                {pairs.map((item, index) => (
                  <div className="pairs" key={index}>
                    {item.map((names, index) => (
                      <Button
                        key={index}
                        handleClick={(e) => this.handleAddWinners(e)}
                        label={names}
                        buttonClass={buttonClick}
                        value={names}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </section>
            ) : round === 2 ? (
              <section className="block__round ">
                {semi.map((names, index) => (
                  <div className="pairs" key={index}>
                    {names.map((names, index) => (
                      <Button
                        key={index}
                        handleClick={(e) => this.handleAddWinners(e, "value")}
                        label={names}
                        buttonClass={buttonClick}
                        value={names}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </section>
            ) : round === 3 ? (
              <section className="block__round ">
                {final.map((names, index) => (
                  <div className="pairs" key={index}>
                    {names.map((names, index) => (
                      <Button
                        key={index}
                        handleClick={(e) => this.handleAddWinners(e, "value")}
                        label={names}
                        buttonClass={buttonClick}
                        value={names}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </section>
            ) : (
              <section className="block__champion">
                <p className="champion__greeting">
                  Congratulations&nbsp;
                  <br />
                  <span className="champion__name">{champName}!</span>
                  <br /> You've won the whole shebang!
                </p>
              </section>
            )}

            <Button
              buttonClass={`${
                round !== 4 ? "block__next-round" : "button__notActive"
              }`}
              label={`${round !== 3 ? "Next Round" : "See Winner"}`}
              handleClick={this.handleRound}
              disabled={disabled}
            />

            <Link to={"/"} className={reset}>
              <Button
                buttonClass={reset}
                handleClick={handleClear}
                label={newGame}
              />
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Matches;
```

This is the component that is handling most of this.

Comment: you gave both of the buttons the buttonClick event - which always set "selected" to true, and you gave them the same class.
Try giving selected a default value of null, send to handleAddWinners the pair index and the key index, and then do a comparrison on the buttonClass to see if the index is the same as selected...

Comment: Could you show an example? I'm sorry I'm struggling to visualise it.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to say that you should always avoid from using array's index as keys. That is, unless your array is always at the same size and order.
Having said that - what you want to do is to know which button was selected - right?
So you need to store the last button that was selected. Because you don't use any ids anywhere, you can use the index of the pair and the index of the button to know which button was clicked.
Here's an example - I've changed only the round1 and the state code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../App.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "../Button/Button";

class Matches extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      champ: [],
      winningPlayers: [],
      selected: null,
    };
    this.handleAddWinners = this.handleAddWinners.bind(this);
    this.handleRound = this.handleRound.bind(this);
  }

  // Adds winners to a local array which is then sent
  // to the global array using the handleNextRound action.

  handleAddWinners = (e, pairIndex, itemIndex) => {
    const winner = e.target.value;
    const { champ } = this.state;
    const { round } = this.props;

    if (round !== 3) {
      this.setState({
        selected: `${pairIndex}-${itemIndex}`,
        winningPlayers: [...this.state.winningPlayers, winner],
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ champ: [...champ, winner] });
    }
  };

  handleRound = () => {
    const { round, handleNextRound, handleChampion } = this.props;

    round !== 3 ? handleNextRound(this.state) : handleChampion(this.state);

    this.setState({ winningPlayers: [] });
  };

  render() {
    const { pairs, round, handleClear, roundWinners, champion } = this.props;
    const { winningPlayers, selected, champ } = this.state;
    const semi = roundWinners[0];
    const final = roundWinners[1];
    const champName = champion.map((item) => item);
    const reset =
      round !== 4 ? "block__reset__tournament" : "block__reset__new-game";
    const newGame = `${round !== 4 ? "Reset" : "New Game?"}`;
    const buttonClick = `${selected ? "selected" : "block__player"}`;
   

    return (
      <>
        <div classname="container__wrapper">
          <div className="container__tournament">
            {round === 1 ? (
              <section className="block__round ">
                {pairs.map((item, pairIndex) => (
                  <div className="pairs" key={pairIndex}>
                    {item.map((names, itemIndex) => (
                      <Button
                        key={itemIndex}
                        handleClick={(e) => this.handleAddWinners(e, pairIndex, itemIndex)}
                        label={names}
                        buttonClass={`${pairIndex}-${itemIndex}` === selected ? '<enterYourBackgroundClass' : buttonClick}
                        value={names}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </section>
            ) : round === 2 ? (
              <section className="block__round ">
                {semi.map((names, index) => (
                  <div className="pairs" key={index}>
                    {names.map((names, index) => (
                      <Button
                        key={index}
                        handleClick={(e) => this.handleAddWinners(e, "value")}
                        label={names}
                        buttonClass={buttonClick}
                        value={names}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </section>
            ) : round === 3 ? (
              <section className="block__round ">
                {final.map((names, index) => (
                  <div className="pairs" key={index}>
                    {names.map((names, index) => (
                      <Button
                        key={index}
                        handleClick={(e) => this.handleAddWinners(e, "value")}
                        label={names}
                        buttonClass={buttonClick}
                        value={names}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </section>
            ) : (
              <section className="block__champion">
                <p className="champion__greeting">
                  Congratulations&nbsp;
                  <br />
                  <span className="champion__name">{champName}!</span>
                  <br /> You've won the whole shebang!
                </p>
              </section>
            )}

            <Button
              buttonClass={`${
                round !== 4 ? "block__next-round" : "button__notActive"
              }`}
              label={`${round !== 3 ? "Next Round" : "See Winner"}`}
              handleClick={this.handleRound}
              disabled={disabled}
            />

            <Link to={"/"} className={reset}>
              <Button
                buttonClass={reset}
                handleClick={handleClear}
                label={newGame}
              />
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Matches;
```

Comment: My hero! thank you so much.  What would I do to keep the selection on as well?

Comment: You need to think of the architecture of what you are trying to achieve...
If you want you can open a private chat and we can talk there